# http to https redirection preventing redirections to other domains

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have following vhost redirecting 80 to 443:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.site.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/htdocs
        Redirect permanent / https://site.mydomain.com

        <Directory /srv/htdocs>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that it does not prevent to redirect to other sites, e.g. by:

http://site.mydomain.com///.s3.amazonaws.com

http://site.mydomain.com/@google.com/

Which rewrite rule would fix such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue ?

```
RedirectMatch "^/$" "https://site.mydomain.com"
```

It should replace your Redirect... line

RedirectMatch will redirect http://site.mydomain.com to https://site.mydomain.com, but not http://site.mydomain.com/about. In order to achieve the latter, you can use following rewrite rule (again, in place of your Redirect line):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: found also https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&version=2.4.41&config=modern&openssl=1.1.1d&guideline=5.6

Answer (score 0):

Add a the trailing `/` to your redirect URL:

```
Redirect permanent / https://site.mydomain.com/
```

Without it, e.g. http://site.mydomain.com/@google.com/ gets redirected
to https://site.mydomain.com@google.com/ where the `/` is missing.